# Acccesing individual tree estimators to predict values from gradient boosting classfiier estimators

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, classification, random-forest, decision-tree

```
gbm0 = GradientBoostingClassifier(n_estimators=500, random_state=42)
%time modelfit(gbm0, X_train, y_train)

##model fit is a fucntion i wrote to create a report on gbm classifier

preds = np.stack([t.predict(X_valid) for t in gbm0.estimators_])
```

gives error

```
  ----> 1 preds = np.stack([t.predict(X_valid) for t in gbm0.estimators_])

 AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'predict'
```

How do i access individual trees predict method to see the predictions ?

Answer (score 0):

The array `estimators_` turns out to have the shape `(n_estimators, 1)` for binary classification. So you can fix the error by reshaping:

```
preds = np.stack([t.predict(X_valid) for t in gbm0.estimators_.reshape(-1)])
```

Comment: Cool. 
This would work too.
`preds = np.stack([t[0].predict(X_valid) for t in gbm0.estimators_])`